# How to prevent My apk from decompiling

Tags: android

Hi
As you now the apk is a zip file, and can be extracted, and the classes.dex can also decompiled, please How to pervent my apk from extracting or decompiling??
Thanks alot

Comment: Is obfuscation is good enough for you?

Comment: just go through [this][1] i found a good thread.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-an-apk-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

[ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html)

Comment: Proguard doesnt prevent decompiling. it just makes it a few harder to read the code.