# how to secure apk from java decompile

Tags: android, security, apk, decompiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent My apk from decompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639225/how-to-prevent-my-apk-from-decompiling)

as you probably know - decompiling APK file is too easy:
extract the apk as zip - reviles compliltly the manifest and all resources.
using simple decompiling software - reviles all the source code (only with not the original variables names..)

I would like to know if there is a way to secure somehow APK file from been decompile.

I assume that reason I need this is obvious to all of you - I don't want people to read the source code or any part of it, from security reasons...

thanks in advance

Comment: Google "reverse engineering" and check out [Proguard](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [proguard](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html). It shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer.

Comment: thanks, 'll check it up letter.  seems like it would be good enough. still don't understand why by default android don't provide better solution to secure apk's

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't. If you root your phone you will always be able to extract the apk and it's contents.

Comment: If you add any video or important matter in assets or raw folder, it will still there when decompiling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use proguard and while done with your coding , you can export the apk file with eclipse with a keystore. This make your application more secure.
[Link to creating keystore.](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)